# Implementing a 15 minute timeout in React issues

Tags: reactjs

I'm implementing a Save feature on a form I'm creating in React. When a User clicks save on a form, I want them to type the username/password. The next time that same user tries to save, if it's been under 15 minutes, I want them to not have to sign the save username/password. If it's over 15, I want them to authenticate again.

I stumbled across this code on a different stackoverflow question about timeouts.

```
   calculateHours(date1 , expireTime){
            const dateOne = date1;
            const dateTwo = new Date();
            const dateOneObj = new Date(dateOne);
            const dateTwoObj = new Date(dateTwo);
            const hours = Math.abs(dateTwoObj - dateOneObj)/ 36e5;
            const minutes = hours/ 36e5;
            return expireTime > hours ? true : false
        }
```

Code for defining the 15 minute timeout currently.

```
  if(this.calculateHours(localStore.time , 15)){
                            this.wrappedClickHandler()
```

This is for a 15 minute timeout, but the code is really sloppy and ugly and I was wondering if anyone has a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a library to handle time, it is not so easy to get better code: You can do some better naming, but the operation is similar:

```js
const isExpired = (startDate, minutes) => {
  startDate = startDate instanceof Date ? startDate : new Date(startDate)
  const diff = new Date() - new Date(startDate)
  const minutesDiff = Math.floor((diff/1000)/60);
  return minutesDiff >= minutes
}
```

Comment: I figured without extra libraries this might be the best way to handle a timeout feature. But the code above is a much cleaner way of implementing. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout. The function will execute after a given time

```
setTimeout(() => {

     ...your necessary code for requiring user to enter username & password...

}, 15 * 60 * 1000) // since time is to be written in milliseconds
```

Comment: that's a really interesting way to implement a timeout. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with time, I always use epochMilli.`new Date().getTime()` then plus 15 minutes is (15*60*1000) milliseconds to be epochExpiresAt kept somewhere(redux?) And then you use the isExpired Function to check every time user click save.

```
const isExpired = (epochExpiresAt) => epochExpiresAt > new Date().getTime()
```